# Pylucene in Python 2.6 + MacOs Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, lucene, pylucene, jcc

Greetings,
I'm trying to install Pylucene on my 32-bit python running on Snow Leopard. I compiled JCC with success. But I get warnings while making pylucene:

```
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/__init__.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/__wrap01__.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/__wrap02__.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/__wrap03__.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/functions.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/JArray.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/JObject.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/lucene.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in build/temp.macosx-10.6-i386-2.6/build/_lucene/types.o, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/JCC-2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg/libjcc.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld: warning: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/JCC-2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.3-fat.egg/libjcc.dylib, file is not of required architecture
build of complete
```

Then I try to import lucene:

```
MacBookPro:~/tmp/trunk python
Python 2.6.3 (r263:75184, Oct  2 2009, 07:56:03) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pylucene
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pylucene
>>> import lucene
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lucene-2.9.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/lucene/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _lucene
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lucene-2.9.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/lucene/_lucene.so, 2): Symbol not found: __Z8getVMEnvP7_object
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lucene-2.9.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/lucene/_lucene.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lucene-2.9.0-py2.6-macosx-10.6-i386.egg/lucene/_lucene.so
>>>
```

Any hints?

Comment: You have compiled jcc for the different architecture - and then you compile pylucene with gcc4-01, and want to build only 32bit.

I can say that on snow leopard, with python 2.6, my preferred python is to set to 32bit, but when i compile both jcc and lucene, the compiler is creating universal binary (both i386 and 64bit)

in pylucene makefile, i use:

JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc.__main__ --shared --arch x86_64 --arch i386

it works

Answer (score 1):

I had to adjust line 44 to 49 in the Makefile to get pylucene to install correctly:

```
PREFIX_PYTHON=/my/virtualenv
ANT=ant
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/bin/python
# add .__main__ to default configuration!
# --arch depends on your architecture of course
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc.__main__ --shared --arch x86_64                                                                                                                                                                      
NUM_FILES=2
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure, but could be as simple as jcc not being installed in the same python location.  To troubleshoot I would try using jcc directly first.  These commands should work even without lucene:

```
>>> import jcc
>>> jcc.initVM(jcc.CLASSPATH)
<jcc.JCCEnv object at 0x1004730d8>
>>> jcc._jcc.getVMEnv()
<jcc.JCCEnv object at 0x1004730f0>
```

And the module name is lucene, btw, not pylucene.

Comment: JCC works, lucene doesn't:

Python 2.6.3 (r263:75184, Oct  2 2009, 07:56:03) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jcc
>>> jcc.initVM(jcc.CLASSPATH)
<jcc.JCCEnv object at 0x333080>
>>> 
MacBookPro:~/tmp/trunk

Comment: I forgot to list getVMEnv()

    >>> jcc._jcc.getVMEnv()  
    <jcc.JCCEnv object at 0x333090>